# Is "what technologies exist to solve this problem" an appropriate question?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, scope

The question is:

> I'm interested in the idea of syndicating/sharing discussions across
>   sites. Many discussion platforms are effectively walled gardens where
>   the operators want to keep you on their site (so they can show you
>   adverts).
>
> But it doesn't have to be like that. I'm sure some sites
>   would be happy to share their conversations (as open data) with other
>   websites and allow  users of these other websites to contribute
>   back, with appropriate  authentication. Does anyone know of any
>   standards or platforms that can achieve this?

I don't think it has one "correct" answer, and it might stimulate discussion, but it is technical and I can't think of a better place to ask it than on Stack Overflow. Can you?

Answer (score 6):

I'd say that's essentially a recommendation/shopping question, and those are indeed not appropriate. As you say there isn't *"one "correct" answer, and it might stimulate discussion"*. Or as the close reason states:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

With regards to "a better place", there wouldn't be one on the network. A site that often comes up for such questions is http://www.slant.co. I can't personally recommend it, since I haven't used it. So perhaps have a look and decide for yourself if that is an appropriate location, and how you might need to modify your question to make it fit there, if possible.

Comment: So I can see how "recommend tools" is a shopping question, because people want to sell tools. But I don't think "recommend standards" is a shopping question, because people don't usually sell standards. Would a question about relevant standards also attract spam? If not, could it be on topic for Stack Overflow or another site on the network?

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of question you want reduced a bit more before it's time to use a tool like Stack Overflow, at least most of the time. It depends a bit on the background, for instance:

> I'm using lint checkers as part of my build / test suite, yet none of them manage to detect when I'm making an assignment in a conditional. Is there a lint checker for POSIX operating systems that can detect this in C99 code? I've used foo, bar, barfoo and foobar with no success.

That's a very narrow question and it's not asking for a recommendation. If a lint checker does this then it's a valid answer, else not, nothing subjective about it. It might be closed, but it's answerable and useful.

> What lint checkers catch the widest sorts of problems in C code? Are there better tools than lint checkers available? Is there some kind of standard that lint checkers should meet?

This is simply way too broad and way too subjective. In the first example, we've already done the work of:

- Determining what problem we're actually solving, then solving for it in our question
- Narrowly scoping the answers that we receive. If an answer doesn't say 'No, there's no tool for that' or 'This tool catches exactly what you want' then it's *wrong*, and not just an unpopular opinion. Answers will ideally name a tool and show me how to use it.
- Narrowed the breadth of the search by specifically saying what didn't work

You could conceivably *get* your question to the point where it would be a decent fit for a Q&A format. What you have is a rather good *discussion*, the fruits of which would likely be excellent building blocks of a great question.

Just keep refining your idea until it looks like something that could have a single *correct* answer, or at least lend to what sorts of answers would *not* be correct. Ideally, you're exploring an actual implementation at this time, and can name a very specific platform.